# Dataset of World Cities, Counties, Localities, Provinces, and States?

Tags: city, json, global

I have a JSON list of international cities with country, latitude, longtitude, but not the corresponding state or province associated with them.
Is there a free database of cities that include what I have plus states and provinces.
If not is there a web service where I can run all my latitudes and longitudes to get the state or province for the city?

Please note this is definitely not a duplicate question the suggested answers are for USA only, I'm asking for all any location in the world.

Comment: definitely not a duplicate question the suggested answers are for USA only, I'm asking for all any location in the world.

Comment: the answers cover the globe; i made sure of each before i even recommended the duplicate flag.

Comment: @yooth - please let us know if the global answers in the other question aren't what you are looking for-

Comment: which link is the global solution? and will they reverse geocode producing cities and their state, province, or other subdivision?

Comment: The links given are either broken or does not answer my question, so it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answers to your questions in the following links; the second question's title is specific, but you can use the geocoders in the answers to get the desired results:

[List of Cities of Each Country](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3835/a-list-of-cities-of-each-country)
[Batch Conversions of Lat/Lon to US Census Tract](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/batch-conversions-of-lat-lon-to-us-census-tract/6384#6384)

Note: Flagging this as a duplicate because your questions already have answers.

Comment: many of the links in the answers are broken.

Comment: many but not all; i checked before i posted...

Comment: that is why there is a need for new reliable answer.

Comment: i get that you are frustrated, but you're going to have to do some of the work here. for the third time: before i flagged this as a duplicate, i walked through both other questions/answers, making sure that they answer the question(s) you have asked.

Comment: your answer is not helpful.